# Django why only string-based field can't have null = true?

Tags: django, django-models, null, field

```
If True, Django will store empty values as NULL in the database. Default is False.

Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and TextField. If a string-based field has null=True, that means it has two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for “no data;” the Django convention is to use the empty string, not NULL. One exception is when a CharField has both unique=True and blank=True set. In this situation, null=True is required to avoid unique constraint violations when saving multiple objects with blank values.
For both string-based and non-string-based fields, you will also need to set blank=True if you wish to permit empty values in forms, as the null parameter only affects database storage (see blank).
```

-- from django/docs --

I understood why string-based fields can't allow to use `null =true` , but what about Integerfield or other fields? they can have also "two possible values for 'nodata' ", right?

and i learned the difference between Null and empty string. why django not allow to use both null and blank for string-based field? why should we treat both NULL and empty string as no data?

Comment: What would an “empty value” be for an int field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django allows the use of `NULL` in string-based fields, it is suggested to avoid it. In other words, Django as a convention recommend the use of `''` to represent the empty value for string-based fields.

The reason of this recommendation, is to avoid redundancy because in most cases both values (`NULL` and `''`) represent the same thing for string-based fields.

Now, if in your case `NULL` and `''` represent different things, then you should use `NULL` string-based fields.

So, don't confuse "Allow" with "Suggestion". The first one is a restriction, while the other is a good practice.